# C++ override inherited methods

Tags: c++, oop, c++11, inheritance

I have the following two classes. Since `Child` inherits from `Father`, I think that `Child::init()` overrides `Father::init()`. Why, when I run the program, I get "I'm the Father" and not "I'm the Child"? How to execute `Child::init()`?

You can test it here: https://ideone.com/6jFCRm

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Father {
    public:
        void start () {
            this->init();
        };

        void init () {
            cout << "I'm the father" << endl;
        };
};

class Child: public Father {
    void init () {
        cout << "I'm the child" << endl;
    };
};

int main (int argc, char** argv) {
    Child child;
    child.start();
}
```

Comment: You didn't make the `init` function virtual (i.e., `virtual void init();`).

Comment: Because init is not `virtual`, and `start` belongs to the `Father` class so it will call the `init` defined there.

Comment: Child's `init()` doesn't override Father's `init()`

Basically `Child::start()` is `Father::init()`.

Comment: I'm surprised that no warning is given for hiding a parent method:(

Comment: Shadowing isn't something to warn about, as sometimes that's really what the coder wants :/

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. `init()` is supposed to only be called from `start()`. If so, I'd make `init()` private in both `Father` and `Child`, not only in `Child` like it is now.

Comment: @АндрейБеньковский If you make `init()` private, than `Child` will not be able to see that it exists, and will not be able to override it. `init()` needs to be made virtual so that derived classes can override it, and therefore it can be at most `protected` instead of `public`

Comment: @RyanP C++ allows overriding private virtual methods. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7e6f146be04bfe76. More on that topic: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/strange-inheritance#private-virtuals

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Currently `Child::init` is *hiding* `Father::init`, not overriding it. Your `init` member function needs to be `virtual` in order to get dynamic dispatch:

```
virtual void init () {
    cout << "I'm the father" << endl;
};
```

Optionally, you could mark `Child::init` as `override` to be explicit that you want to override a virtual function (requires C++11):

```
void init () override {
    cout << "I'm the child" << endl;
};
```

Comment: when there is not virtual, this evaluates to a pointer to base class at compile time since there is not late binding, is this what you mean? Because if it is not virtual, and init was public, child.init() prints child. So is this pointer the reason for this behaviour?

Comment: The other purpose of the "override" keyword is to let the compiler check and make sure that the both methods in the base and derived class have the same signatures. If the method in the derived class uses the keyword "override" but its signature does not match any method in the base class, then the compiler will error out.

Answer (score 5):

You should define the function with function specifier `virtual`

For example

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Father {
    public:
        virtual ~Father() {}

        void start () {
            this->init();
        };

        virtual void init () const {
            cout << "I'm the father" << endl;
        };
};

class Child: public Father {
    void init () const override {
        cout << "I'm the child" << endl;
    };
};

int main()
{
    Child child;
    child.start();

    return 0;
}
```

Otherwise function `start` searches name `init` in the scope of its own class. And because function `init` is not virtual that is it is not overriden in the derived class the base class function init is called.

Comment: when there is not virtual, this evaluates to a pointer to base class at compile time since there is not late binding, is this what you mean?

Answer (score 3):

If you want the child to override the init method, you must make the `init` method in the base class `virtual`.

```
class Father {
    public:
        void start () {
            this->init();
        };

        virtual void init () {
            cout << "I'm the father" << endl;
        };
};
```

A class that re-declares and re-implements a virtual method of one of its bases, is said to override that method. In order for late binding to occur for a method, you need to declare that method `virtual`.